# Jenkins Android build :app:mergeDebugResources problem

Tags: android, jenkins

I am trying to configure project on local Jenkins v2.150.2 (Windows) to build my android application using gradle wrapper. I spend many hour but I still get following error durrning mergeDebugResources.

> Task :app:cleanBuildCache
>   Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug
>   Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
>     C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\17dd212fa1026015c542616bd4b41905\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.

So far I read that path length shouldn't be longer than 255 characters on Windows. I could find global workspace location for all project in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure system, (propably no longer availible) so I changed workspace path only for single job (project). After that I saw that Jenkins copied some files to selected location including .gradle and gradle wrapper, but as You can se in error log it still uses those from C:\Windows\System32. I'm not sure if thats the problem but I don't no how to change it. It would be awesome if I could Store all Jenkins caches workspaces and builds in custom localization for all projects to make it clear.

In other post I read that abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png may be corrupted and removing it from project often helps. That's weird cause Android Studio has no problem with that, and to be honest I don't know how to remove this file.

I hope you will help to find me the solution, and thanks for your time.

Comment: this question completely lacks the `build.gradle`, which produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

this is a Windows-specific issue; update the Gradle plugin to:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
```

Comment: Yes, I updated Gradle to newest version, and it didn't help.

Comment: @MaciejGrodzki that path only has 161 characters; similar questions & answers hint for cleaning the project, corrupt nine-patch files, or providing libraries (which would be `DLL` on Windows). without the `build.gradle` this behavior barely is reproducible. `mergeDebugResources` is even non-sense, because that library should be built in release mode; putting something strange into the resources, eg. a `JPG` renamed to `PNG` also can cause that, `aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false` & `aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false` are only workarounds, while the problem might be such corrupt file.

Comment: PS: Windows 10 doesn't even have any NTFS 255 character limit for the path anymore... checking all `drawable` resource file headers might be the best option to find the corrupt file; the first 8 bytes of a `PNG` file should always be `137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10`. it all hints for the cruncher receiving input which it cannot handle (or messed up cache files). checkout a fresh copy from version control, let Jenkins clean up the workspace before the build.  see http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html and https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container for specs.